# if i apply draggable to a div wrapper, how to i resolve the case of click dragging the child input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a small segment of code:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

and want to make it draggable:

```
$("div").draggable();
```

it works if we drag the div, but if you click-drag on the textbox, a stopPropigation seems to be called (possibly from within the focus event).

How would we resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div").draggable({cancel:null});
```

will get it working.  it removes the default flags determined by the jQuery API.

see:  http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/XPN5h/